# Web scraping using perl

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I might ask something stupid but I want to learn some web scraping. I already know how to use perl, so I would prefer to do it using this language. I know there are a lot of modules on CPAN, I tried to read those but I barely understand something. I haven't found anthing that would explain from zero what this process means. I could use some help with some links or some materials to study a little web scraping.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, what? You want to learn about web scraping, but you don't know what it is? How do you know that you want to learn it?

Answer (score 2):

At a pretty basic level, 'web scraping' is just downloading a webpage, and parsing it to extract the information you want. At a started level, the module you want is `LWP` that lets you fetch content, and then 'something' to extract the information you want. `HTML::Parser` or `HTML::TableExtract` for example. There's nothing to say you can't roll your own using pattern matching of course, but ... well, processing HTML isn't a new problem, so why re-invent the wheel?

At a more advanced level though, you might want to interact with a site - log in to it perhaps, or 'click through' some menus. For this, I like `WWW::Mechanize`.

I'm afraid I can't give you much more without a better understanding of the sort of problem you're trying to solve though. Are you at a basic 'fetch a webpage and parse' sort of level?

(You can find details and examples of the above modules on CPAN. The LWP page has some examples that should get you started.)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a pretty basic tutorial on WWW::Mechanize [here](http://perlmonks.com/?node_id=1037506)
..I have successfully crawled pages on several occasions so please let me know if you have a case you would like to try and need some help :)

Answer (score 1):

To start you can look at WWW::Mechanize and HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath modules.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the best module for web scraping is [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper). Its language can be quite terse at times, but there are plenty of [examples](https://metacpan.org/source/MIYAGAWA/Web-Scraper-0.37/eg).